# Empty space in Highcharts when useUTC is set to false

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I disable `useUTC` to show events in local time, Highcharts is adding empty space on the left of the graph.

[image]

If I set `useUTC` to `true`, it works fine.

Code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/ncbm7p4j/6/

Comment: In HighCharts : Time options that can apply globally or to individual charts. These settings affect how datetime axes are laid out, how tooltips are formatted. As per the fiddle code shared, the timestamp is provided as data in the series & highchart is trying to figure out the timezone associated with thi, which it is not able to recognize.
Here comes the play of setting the timezone either by specifically providing it explicitly or making the useUTC flag true

`time: {
        timezone: 'Europe/London',
        //useUTC: false/true
}`

Comment: @JayaParwani Thanks for the heads-up about `timezone`. I've set it to Indian time now globally, but it does not affect the time displayed on x-axis. All my times are in GMT zone. I've updated the fiddle to reflect this: https://jsfiddle.net/ncbm7p4j/8/

Comment: You need to be more specific, what you need on x axis. As far as if you want to change the time displayed on axis you need to use `yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 36 * 1000,
    type: "datetime",
  }`  for 30 seconds change.

Comment: @JayaParwani I mean the times I get from API are in GMT +0. But when I show these times on Highcart's x-axis, they still show up in GMT+0, not in my timezone which is GMT+5:30

Comment: Are you sure that this demo reproduces the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4wn21ymz/ I cannot see this gap on the left.